# iOS: opening app with custom URL if installed, itunes otherwise

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking, custom-url

I implemented a [smart app banner](https://github.com/asianmack/play-store-smartbanner) for my website in order to redirect user to our Android or iOS app. By parsing the user agent I could successfully redirect to Android app or Google Play Store (using an intent filter): now I'd like to do the same for iOS, opening the app if it's installed and opening iTunes elsewhere.

I managed to open the app, if it's installed, by using a Custom URL Scheme

```
<a href="myurlscheme://main">
```

Now I'd like to make iTunes start if the app is not installed on device. How can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, this is kind of a pain to implement on your own. After you've detected the iOS user agent, you could implement a JavaScript redirection on your server something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/path/to/your/app/";
}, 25);

// If "yourapp://" is registered, the user will see a dialog
// asking if want to open your app. If they agree, your app will 
// launch  immediately and the timer won't fire.
// If not installed, you'll get an ugly "Cannot Open Page" 
// dialogue and the App Store will launch when the timer expires.

window.location = "yourapp://";
```

Obviously this isn't an ideal solution and it has a ton of nasty edge cases, most notably the 'Cannot Open Page" error users will see before being redirected to the App Store if they don't have your app installed. Until recently, it was possible to get around this in a reasonably user-friendly way by using a more nuanced version of this script. Sadly, Apple [intentionally broke that](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links) with the iOS 9.2 update.

You could also [enable Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9). Apple knows this is an annoying problem and is trying to help. Universal Links let you use a normal URL to a page on your website (which could be a simple redirection to the App Store *without* the custom URL trigger that causes the 'Cannot Open Page' error), which is intercepted by your phone and sent directly into your app if installed. Unfortunately Universal Links only work in iOS 9+, and don't work yet when opened inside a lot of apps.

The best solution is a combination of the above methods: Universal Links and Applinks everywhere they are supported, and intelligent JavaScript redirections as a fallback. This is quite a lot to handle, so the best option might be a free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) (full disclosure: I work with the team) to take care of all the technical aspects.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this works flawlessly (except for the small, not-so-annoying popup "would you like to open this link with the app YOURAPP").

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<meta"apple-itunes-app"content"app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL"`

or

```
<a href="xxx://www.xxx.com">Open APP</a>
```

Comment: Thank you Lee. The first suggestion works but it's a meta tag that (I could be wrong) works only on Safari so it's not what I need. The second one simply does not work, it only opens the app if I already installed it :-/